# Simple count down timer in Android development

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

So Ive created a mobile app using java with a simple timer starting from 0 to 50 seconds .How can I make this timer go from 50s to 0.Like a count down timer. Please help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public int counter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView counttime=findViewById(R.id.counttime);
    new CountDownTimer(50000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            counttime.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            counter++;
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            counttime.setText("Finished");
        }
    }.start();

}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you use [CountdownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer/) defined in android os. It quite simple and robust to use with minimal overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the `counter` variable since the `onTick` method provides you the count-down value.

```
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        counttime.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
    }
```

If you only want to show seconds, divide it by 1000.